# Access HttpServletRequest from an Authenticator using Dropwizard

Tags: dependency-injection, jersey, dropwizard

Using DropWizard(Jersey Server), Is it possible to access `HttpServletRequest` from an Authenticator?

I would give it an attribute.

I tried with:

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
```

But it's not injected.

I registered my Authenticator using:

```
env.jersey().register(
                new AuthDynamicFeature(new BasicCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<User>().setAuthenticator(new FooAuthentificator())
                        .setRealm("Realm").buildAuthFilter()));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible, but the problem is, the `Authenticator` never goes through the DI lifecycle, so it never gets a chance to get injected. What we *can* do though is explicitly inject it ourselves. To do that, we need to get a hold of the `ServiceLocator` (which is the main IoC container, kind of like `ApplicationContext` with Spring). Once we have the `ServiceLocator`, we can call `locator.inject(anyObject)` to explicitly resolve any injection dependencies.

The easiest place to get the `ServiceLocator`, when configuring the app, is in a `Feature`. Here we can also register Jersey components. Calling `register` on the `FeatureContext` (seen below) is just like calling `env.jersey().register(...)` with Dropwizard, it has the same effect. So we can do

```
public class AuthenticatorFeature implements Feature {

    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext ctx) {
        ServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocatorProvider.getServiceLocator(ctx);
        TestAuthenticator authenticator = new TestAuthenticator();
        locator.inject(authenticator);
        ctx.register(new AuthDynamicFeature(new BasicCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<User>()
                        .setAuthenticator(authenticator)
                        .setRealm("SEC REALM")
                        .buildAuthFilter()));
        ctx.register(new AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<>(User.class));
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can see that explicitly inject the authenticator, with the call to `locator.inject(authenticator)`. Then we register this feature through Dropwizard

```
env.jersey().register(new AuthenticatorFeature());
```

Tested, and works fine.

---

Note, if you are wondering how it's possible to inject the `HttpServletRequest`, when there is no current request, it's because a proxy is injected. Same thing as if you were to inject the request into a Jersey filter, the same thing happens; a proxy is injected, as there is only a singleton filter, but the request changes from request to request, so a proxy needs to be injected.

**See Also:**

- [Injecting Request Scoped Objects into Singleton Scoped Object with HK2 and Jersey](http://paulsamsotha.blogspot.com/2015/12/injecting-request-scoped-objects-into.html)