# HTTPServletRequest and HTTPServletResponse not being filled with @Context

Tags: dependency-injection, jax-rs

I'm really new to DI and am having tons of problems with basic things in JAX-RS.

I have a filter called `SentryAuthFilter` which subclasses an abstract class called `AuthFilter`. `AuthFilter` implements `ContainerRequestFilter`, `ContainerResponseFilter` and `WriterInterceptor`. Because `AuthFilter` is abstract, the methods, like `configure()`, `matchResource()`, ... are implemented actually in `SentryAuthFilter()` (and other classes that subclass `AuthFilter`.

In `SentryFilter`, I need access to the `HTTPServletRequest` and `HTTPServletResponse` in my `filter` method.

```
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class SentryAuthFilter extends AuthFilter {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Context
    private HttpServletResponse response;

    ...



@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    SentryHttpServletResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new SentryHttpServletResponseWrapper(response);
    try {
        tomcatSSOFilter.doFilter(request, responseWrapper, (request1, response1) -> {});
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error occurred executing TomcatSSOFilter", e);
        requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(e.getMessage()).build());
        return;
    }

    ...
 }
```

The problem is that `request` and `response` is null. I've looked at 8 different questions regarding this topic and I can't find one that explains how HTTPServletRequest and HTTPServletResponse are injected. They just say that it is a singleton proxy object and you shouldn't need to explicitly inject it, just use `@Context`. Clearly, `@Context` is not working.

The class that actually calls `SentryFilter` or any of the other classes that implement `AuthFilter` is called `DynamicAuthFilter`. This `DynamicAuthFilter` is "registered" in a class that implements `DynamicFeature`

```
@Provider
public class AuthenticationDynamicFeature implements DynamicFeature {

    private final List<javax.inject.Provider<? extends AuthFilter>> filterProviders;

    /**
     * @param permissionAuthFilter permissionAuthFilter
     * @param aaaAuthFilter aaaAuthFilter
     * @param sentryAuthFilter sentryAuthFilter
     */
    @Inject
    public AuthenticationDynamicFeature(final javax.inject.Provider<SomeAuthFilter> someAuthFilter,
                                        final javax.inject.Provider<AnotherAuthFilter> anotherAuthFilter,
                                        final javax.inject.Provider<SentryAuthFilter> sentryAuthFilter) {
        this.filterProviders = ImmutableList.of(someAuthFilter, anotherAuthFilter, sentryAuthFilter);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(final ResourceInfo resourceInfo, final FeatureContext context) {

            List<AuthFilter> filters = filterProviders.stream()
                    .map(javax.inject.Provider::get)
                    .filter(f -> f.matchResource(resourceInfo))
                    .peek(AuthFilter::configure)
                    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), ImmutableList::copyOf));

        context.register(new DynamicAuthFilter(filters));
    }
}
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44097938/context-injection-not-working-in-jersey-containerrequestfilter-dropwizard), it seems like context registration is how @Context values are filled. So I'm not sure if the issue is that registration in `AuthenticationDynamicFeature` is wrong, or if I'm missing something else. `DynamicAuthFilter` does nothing else except call `SentryFilter`, `AnotherAuthFilter`, etc, so I don't use `@Context` in it.

Sorry for the long post, but I'm really confused.

Comment: Maybe [just manually inject it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35953104/2587435)

Comment: I saw that post. How do I get access to the HTTPServletRequest and Response object? In that post the guy explicitly passes in `authenticator`, but where would I get the `request` or `response`?

Comment: You inject the filter. You have the filter. locator.inject(filter)

Comment: So use `ServiceLocator` to inject it, then register it? How will that fill in the request and response values? The filter itself needs those values, so how would injecting the filter make @Context inject HTTPServletRequest and HTTPServletResponse?

Comment: You don't need to register it. Just inject it. The locator will inject a proxy. Read the rest of the post

Comment: I did read it, but I'm just confused with what specifically to inject. That whole `List<AuthFilter> filters...` line is important because it collects the different filters that are specified for a particular API based on annotations. `DynamicAuthFilter` is needed to actually call those filters. So are you saying my `configure` method should only be the `List<AuthFilter> filters` line, then create a DynamicAuthFilter object passing in filters, and then using `ServiceLocator` to inject `DynamicAuthFilter`?

Comment: Use the locator to inject any object you want injected. Is the the DynamicAuthFilter you want injected? No. You are already passing all the filters to it. What you want to inject is the filter that is not getting the request and response, the SentryAuthFilter

Comment: Alright, is there a way other than ServiceLocator to inject SentryFilter? Apparently getting ServiceLocator in jersey isn't trivial.

Comment: You should just be able to inject it into your feature. It's a service like any other service.

Comment: Do you have an example of this? When I tried it I got errors?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/6ac7816b4bf17eaebb87a876e7c730c7

Comment: I think I need to bind the ServiceLocator, otherwise i get "No implementation" errors, which comes back to my first point of how to "get" or make a ServiceLocator

Comment: What version of Jersey are you using?

Comment: Jersey 2.19 it seems

Comment: Should work. Did you run my test?

Comment: I implemented your changes in my `AuthenticationDynamicFeature`. I added ServiceLocator to my Constructor that already has an @Inject and used `locator.inject(sentryAuthFilter) there. There's not really another place where I can inject it. I can't inject it in configure because I can't easily make a `SentryAuthFilter` (it has arguments passed to it's constructor) which I don't think should me instantiated in AuthenticationDynamicFeature.

Comment: How can you do that when it is a Provider and not the actual filter? Just do it in the map method on your stream

Comment: so instead of `.map(javax.inject.Provider::get)` do `.map(this.locator.inject(javax.inject.Provider))`? That fails with Object is not a functional interface

Comment: 1) get the filter from the provider, 2) inject the filter, 3) return the filter.